# how to create node path similar to the sling job creates

Tags: aem, sling, jcr

AEM6.2 - I want to create a node hierarchy similar to the sling creates under "/var/eventing/..".

It should be based as "var/eventing/xx/year/month/date/hours/minutes/seconds/milisenconds/<>"
How do you suggest - to create each folder node by iterating the date format "YYYY/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss/SSS" ?
Or is there any other best way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ResourceUtil.getOrCreateResource](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling11/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceUtil.html#getOrCreateResource-org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-java.lang.String-boolean-) method. Pass the complete path you need and it will create all the sub directories if it does not already exist

```
String VAR_DATA_ROOT = "/var/eventing";
Date currentDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("/YYYY/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss/SSS");
String bucketPath = VAR_DATA_ROOT+simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate);
Resource bucketResource = ResourceUtil.getOrCreateResource(resourceResolver,bucketPath,null,null,false);
//save the data under bucketResource
resourceResolver.commit();
```